# What statistical test should I use when finding the relationship between average time spent on social media and academic attention span?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, survey

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you tell us how do you measure the variables mentioned in the title?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you operationalize the two variables the relationship of which you're trying to quantify, and whether you've identified one as your independent variable (IV) and the other as your dependent variable (DV).

If you have not yet assigned your IV and DV, and assuming both are quantitative continuous following the Gaussian distribution, then Pearson's correlation can be used.  Otherwise, use Spearman's rank correlation if the distribution is non-normal.

On the other hand, if you plan on categorizing both variables, then chi-square or Fisher's exact test can be used.

From reading your question, I'm assuming your hypothesis is that the average time on spends on social media (IV) affects the length of their academic attention span (DV).  If your DV is quantitative continuous (regardless of whether your IV is quantitative or categorical), you can perform linear regression analysis.  You may need to test for any assumption violations as well.  However, if your DV is categorical, you may need to use logistic regression analysis.